# Kubuntu 18.04 boots to black screen after installing Nvidia drivers version 396

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I am running *Kubuntu 18.04* with a GTX 980. I installed *NVidia driver version 396*, and now the machine boots to a black screen. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> do not do anything at any time while the machine is booting.

How can I fix this?

Comment: File a bug with nvidia - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/ - and use the open source driver until nvidia fixes their closed source driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, my computer wasn't outputting any signal from my Nvidia card, and when I connected my onboard Intel graphics to the monitor, I was able to see everything, and make changes to my drivers.